# Is inverse CNF polynomial?

Tags: satisfiability

Suppose we are given a CNF formula $F$ with $n$ variables and $m$ clauses. The question is whether we can represent $\lnot F$ as a CNF formula with the number of clauses polynomial in $n$ and $m$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not necessarily.

If $F$ is $(\neg X_1 \lor \neg Y_1) \land \dots \land (\neg X_n \lor \neg Y_n)$, then expressing $\neg F$ in CNF requires exponentially $2^n$ clauses.  See, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form#Conversion_into_CNF, [Which CNF boolean formulas blow up exponentially at conversion to DNF?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/35209/755), and [Formulas for which any equivalent CNF formula has exponential length](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/18409/755).

However, if you allow introducing additional variables, then you can construct a formula $G$ that is equisatisfiable with $\neg F$ and such that $G$ can be represented in CNF with number of variables and clauses polynomial in $n$ and $m$.

Comment: Cool. This example is exactly what I used in my [previous question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/113342). Can you carry on to show that the "partial question" on that page is impossible? Actually this question arised when I was thinking about that question.

Comment: I think the disjointness of clauses is central to the possibility of polynomial SAT solving. How do you handle that? By disjointness, I mean two clauses differ in their variables. They could have a common part, but I haven't thought of that case yet. When they differ in variables, there will be a lot of interactions in the $n$-dimensional search space, which could lead to exponentiality.